# eaRep object in Linux environment?

Tags: python, linux, com, enterprise-architect

I recently learnt that EA can be installed in a Debian system using Wine. I was wondering if there is way to then access the eaRep (EA Repository) object programmatically in Linux. For example, if we are talking about Python what would be the Linux equivalent of,

```
eaRep = win32com.client.Dispatch('EA.Repository')
eaRep.OpenFile("Model.eapx")
```

Tried looking up documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My last try under wine is long ago but basically it works. You probably have to tweak your code to

```
eaApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("EA.App")
eaRep = eaApp.Repository
```

That will open a running EA instance. This is basically the way I'm using it. But once you have it up it should be not a big deal to create a new EA instance and then call open. IIRC you need something else than `Dispatch`. The `win32com` docs should give you the right direction, though I remember there was same voodoo involved (well, it's Windoze).